# Scape issue in beautiful soup, NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nonetype

Trying to execute this code for scraping the specific websites / rss feeds metioned here below
keep getting :

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Jeanne\Desktop\PYPDIT\pyscape.py", line 28, in 
    transcripts = [url_to_transcript(u) for u in urls]

File "C:\Users\Jeanne\Desktop\PYPDIT\pyscape.py", line 28, in 
    transcripts = [url_to_transcript(u) for u in urls]

File "C:\Users\Jeanne\Desktop\PYPDIT\pyscape.py", line 17, in url_to_transcript
    text = [p.text for p in soup.find(class_="itemcontent").find_all('p')]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Please advise.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pickle

def url_to_transcript(url):

page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
text = [p.text for p in soup.find(class_="itemcontent").find_all('p')]
print(url)
return text
```

## URLs of transcripts in scope

```
urls = ['http://feeds.nos.nl/nosnieuwstech',
        'http://feeds.nos.nl/nosnieuwsalgemeen']

transcripts = [url_to_transcript(u) for u in urls]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html returned is not the same as you see on the page. You can use the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 # import pickle

urls = ['http://feeds.nos.nl/nosnieuwstech','http://feeds.nos.nl/nosnieuwsalgemeen']

with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        page = s.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
        print(url)
        print([[i.text for i in desc.select('p')] for desc in soup.select('description')[1:]])
        print('--'*100)
```

Comment: Thank you, this has worked well for this beautifully.

Comment: # # Pickle files for later use

# # Make a new directory to hold the text files
# !mkdir transcripts

# for i, c in enumerate(comedians):
#     with open("transcripts/" + c + ".txt", "wb") as file:
#         pickle.dump(transcripts[i], file)

Can you help me with the next step, how do I pickle the selected text?

Comment: Hiya, Please open a new question. Add your attempt and explain what isn't working and what you have tried.

Comment: I have made a new question, maybe you could help me out with this next step .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61558832/how-do-i-pickle-the-scrape-data-instead-of-printing-the-data